# Remove From Disk Deleted projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I Know that from the web interface you can delete projects, but their corresponding folders are still in disk with "deleted" attached to their name. Can I just manually delete this folders or is there a gitlabctl command to do this ??